# Bevel Start End on Circle Curve, Blender 2.83 not working

Tags: bevel

The Bevel Start End does not work on closed curves.

I need to partially bevel a profile on a circle.
The circle curve added by Add->Curve->Circle is closed.

Duplicating a vertex and manually re-building an open circle results in a numerically inprecise curve.

How can I open the Circle curve without loosing a segment and end up with a mathematically exact circle?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either Blender is rather non-intuitive, or I'm missing something obvious.
The fastest way I found:

1. Add a bezier circle and make it non-cyclic (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
2. Rotate the end vertices to form a 3/4 circle
3. Extrude one of the ends and complete the circle

[image]

[image]

[image]